OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)"
Why can't I read Excel files using OLE DB in local SQL Server after installing the same version as the one on the company server (2022)? Although I have installed OLE DB, I keep getting the following error: "OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' for linked server '(null)' returned message 'Failure creating file'".
Execute
Error
I have tried uninstalling SQL Server, installing OLE DB, and also downloading and installing accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe. Why doesn't it work for me?
tambien eh intentado con
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1 RECONFIGURE GO EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 RECONFIGURE GO EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 GO EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 GO

Please edit your question, and remove all the images, and replace them within the question as text.

Please run the following statement, and add it to the question what it emits: EXEC master.sys.sp_MSset_oledb_prop;

Your error is as follows:

Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 41 Cannot initialize the data source
object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server
"(null)".

Please try the following steps:

If the *.xslx file is open in Excel. Close it in Excel.
Run SSMS as administrator.
Give MSSQLSERVER full permission on this folder:
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles<SQL Server Service account
name>\AppData\Local\Temp

On my machine account: NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
So, my temp files when I query MS Excel files:

c:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MSSQLSERVER\AppData\Local\Temp\JET643E.tmp
c:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\MSSQLSERVER\AppData\Local\Temp\JET642E.tmp


The solution wasn't specifically that Excel was being used by another program, temporary Excel files, etc., however, it was to run SSMS as administrator. , Thnx Bro <3
